GaN half bridge in self-oscillating class D amplifier
Context:
I am in the process of designing my own self-oscillating class D amplifier (in my spare time, this is just a hobby project).
Since GaN devices seem to be getting cheaper and more readily avaible lately, I'd like to evaluate whether using a GaN half bridge could make sense for such an amplifier.
Possible advantages I am curious about include higher efficiency, less PCB space and a higher switching frequency (which I am hoping might improve distortion).
To answer this question I'd like to build a prototype amplifier using a GaN half bridge so I can measure the performance parameters I am interested in.
Because of that, the overall topology is pretty much already set.
Sure, I could build a better, cheaper amplifier using off-the-shelf controller ICs and matching switches in far less time.
But thats besides the point - I am doing this project out of fun and curiosity about self-oscillating amplifiers and new technologies like GaN.
My Question:
So far I've only seen half bridge modules (with an integrated gate driver) having two logic level inputs, high in and low in. Both referenced to the negative supply rail (probably -48V in my case).
To drive these with a PWM signal from a comparator that is referenced to ground, I therefore need to do the following:

Convert the PWM signal into individual control signals for the high side and low side switch with appropriate dead time
Shift both control signals from +5V/GND to -43V/-48V

Ideally, I would like to do both with a single IC.
Gate driver ICs like the Si8274 are the first thing that came to my mind.
Could I (mis)use such a gate driver to drive logic level inputs? Or would that bring additional problems?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Driving the gate of an HEMT isn't very much like driving the gate of a MOSFET. I wouldn't expect your average MOSFET gate driver to work here.

Yes, that's true. But I was mainly interested in half bridge modules with integrated gate drivers. I don't think the original question conveyed that part very well, so I've edited it.
There are specific gate driver ICs optimized for GaN though.

@thebear8 Please provide a schematic.

@VoltageSpike I've added a general schematic
